# Problems with checklist with KnockoutJS + CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple checklist with KnockoutJS and CoffeScritp;

For this I created a class in coffescript to represent the task.
In this class I have a computed property `HasFinalized` to represent the check.
Basically, if the completion date is met, then the task is completed.

But any change in a task, it is propagated to another.

I created an example in Findlee:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/pr3Ah/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the instance variables in the constructor or they are shared by all instances (because then they belong to the prototype). Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pr3Ah/6/).

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I've never used knockout.js before. But I watched the introduction video and think it's pretty cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified and rewritten your script,so template can be applied.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVyuC/

As I am only a beginner of Knockout, cannot clearly explain why your script did not work,
but I think the reason is you bind HasFinalized to checkbox but not an ko.observable object which is Finalized.

Hope you can understand my words & you can find more examples in Knockout's Documentation.
Template binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html